# Samsung Galaxy S4 loads all items in RecyclerView upon start

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, samsung-galaxy

I've encountered an issue with the RecyclerView loading all items upon start and triggering 200+ loads of images which causes OutOfMemoryException.

```
@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    Holder holder = new Holder(view);
    return holder;
}
```

I'm using the usual way of setting items to the adapter with RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

Encountered on Samsung Galaxy S4: GT-I9506 - Android-version 5.0.1

Anyone else found this issue? Have been encountered on other devices as well.

**Edit**

Exception:

```
09-20 07:35:59.666 25016-25889/smartapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 172 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM" (recursive case)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art: "Picasso-/image-url” prio=5 tid=45 Runnable
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x133ad0e0 self=0xad5df000
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:   | sysTid=25889 nice=10 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xad52e300
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 906109587 479948169 1066 ) utm=73 stm=17 core=1 HZ=100
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:   | stack=0x92c56000-0x92c58000 stackSize=1036KB
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:163)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:295)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.MarkableInputStream.read(MarkableInputStream.java:138)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.isWebPFile(Utils.java:324)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:122)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-20 07:35:59.686 25016-25889/smartapp E/art:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)


09-20 07:35:58.746 25016-25016/smartapp D/Picasso: Main        created      [R373] Request{https://image-url}
09-20 07:35:58.746 25016-25016/smartapp D/Picasso: Main        created      [R374] Request{https://image-url}
09-20 07:35:58.746 25016-25216/smartapp D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R373]+1ms 
09-20 07:35:58.746 25016-25216/smartapp D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R374]+1ms 
09-20 07:35:58.746 25016-25016/smartapp D/Picasso: Main        created      [R375] Request{https://image-url}
09-20 07:35:58.786 25016-25889/smartapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
09-20 07:35:58.786 25016-25889/smartapp I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 622(21KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 891us total 54.100ms
09-20 07:35:58.846 25016-25889/smartapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
09-20 07:35:58.846 25016-25889/smartapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17(704B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 826us total 54.652ms
09-20 07:35:58.846 25016-25889/smartapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2MB allocation
09-20 07:35:58.846 25016-25036/smartapp I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 120.065ms for cause Background
09-20 07:35:58.846 25016-25891/smartapp I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 132.562ms for cause Alloc
```

Comment: can you post the complete exception

Comment: this cannot happen. only those items are loaded in recycler view which are visible at a time.... but there can be a case let suppose you have 10 items on recyclerview visble and images you are using those are heavy or very high resolution images

Comment: Yes, I know... That should be the usual behaviour... But somehow this is not happening on Galaxy S4 phone, but trying it on a S6 device, everything works as intended.

Comment: S6 have a larger memory that is why it's not crashing in that. You have to re-size your images or use Picasso,Glide or any other libraries that already handle this for you.

Comment: I think you are already using Picasso from the logs. Try resize(x, y);

Comment: The issue is not with large image sizes, but the fact that all items are pre-rendered when starting the adapter. It's not the usual lazyLoad pattern being shown on the S6. I've never encountered this before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the RecyclerView was located inside a ScrollView, which triggered the fetch of all items..!

By simply removing the ScrollView as parent, replacing it by a LinearLayout the normal smoothness was achieved.

A stupid mistake, but I hope someone else can learn from my mistake.